# Filter web3.eth.getTransactionCount() based on transaction type

Tags: javascript, blockchain, web3js

I'm using this line of code to get all the transaction counts under a particular contract.

```js
web3.eth.getTransactionCount("//contract address").then(console.log);
```

But I only want to count the transactions where the minting of NFTs was done.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, there are six transactions, and getTransactionCount() would return six. But I only want to count those transactions which have the method "Mint NFT".

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The web3 `getTransactionCount()` function ([docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.0/web3-eth.html#gettransactioncount)) is a wrapper to the `eth_getTransactionCount` JSON-RPC method ([docs](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_gettransactioncount)) returning the amount of mined transactions sent **from** the specified address.

Since your code specifies the "contract address", I'm assuming that you want to return the amount of transactions performing the specified action on the contract address - by any caller.

Mind that the "Mint NFT" in the "Method" column of the screenshot simply represents the executed function name. It does not mean that an NFT was in fact mined. So theoretically you can have a following function named `mintNFT()` that performs a totally different action:

```
function mintNFT() external {
    // does not mint any NFT
    counter++;
}
```

Also - and this is important for the next paragraph - a contract can contain multiple functions with the same name that result in different function selectors because they have different parameter datatypes.

```
// all of these can be in the same contract
mintNFT(address to) // selector `0x54ba0f27`
mintNFT(address to, uint256 ID) // selector `0x3c168eab`
mintNFT(uint256 ID) // selector `0x92642744`
```

So if you want to filter by the invoked function, you'll need to know (or calculate) its specific selector - not just the function name. It's the first 4 bytes (8 hex characters) of the keccak-256 hash of the function name, following argument datatypes separated by comma, wrapped in parentheses. Example:

```
// keccak-256 hash of this string, first 4 bytes
// and you get the `0x3c168eab` selector mentioned earlier
mintNFT(address,uint256)
```

Finally, there is no native way (in the Ethereum JSON-RPC API that some other blockchains, such as Polygon or BSC, implement as well) to get a list of transactions sent or received by an address. Since web3 is a wrapper library to the JSON-RPC API (plus it contains a few related helpers and utility functions), there's no way to achieve this result using web3.

So you'll need to collect all existing transactions (at least in the block range that you're interested in) to a searchable database. Or - to use an already existing searchable collection.

For the purpose of this answer, I'm going to be using the [PolygonScan API](https://docs.polygonscan.com/api-endpoints/accounts#get-a-list-of-normal-transactions-by-address), which is free for limited use, as your question suggests the target contract is on Polygon. And [this contract](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x90410a6bc2285df5a726b0b89d8be60c9b6fa26e#code) that implements two functions with the same name (`mint()`) but different function selectors. Lets use the latter defined function from line 2003:

```
function mint(
    address to,
    uint32 batch,
    uint32 sequence,
    uint32 limit,
    string memory name,
    string memory page,
    string memory description,
    string memory link,
    string memory content,
    string memory created
)
```

The selector is calculated from the following string

```
mint(address,uint32,uint32,uint32,string,string,string,string,string,string)
```

and its value is `0xab2a6d77`.

Then the process is straightforward. Once you get the list of all transactions **to** the contract address, you simply filter them by the chosen function selector, which is always the first 4 bytes of the `data` field of the raw transaction (named as `input` in the API).

Note that it's possible to send a transaction to a contract having less than 4 bytes in the `data` field (usually 0), so your code should also account for that.

```
const axios = require("axios");

const API_KEY = "YourApiKeyToken";

const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0x90410A6bc2285dF5A726b0b89D8bE60C9B6fA26E";
const SELECTOR = "0xab2a6d77";

const run = async () => {
    const allTransactions = await _getAllTransactionsTo(CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
    const filteredTransactions = _filterTransactionsBySelector(allTransactions, SELECTOR);
    const txHashes = _getTransactionHashes(filteredTransactions);
    console.log(txHashes);
}

const _getAllTransactionsTo = async (address) => {
    const response = await axios(
        "https://api.polygonscan.com/api"
        + "?module=account"
        + "&action=txlist"
        + "&address=" + address
        + "&startblock=0"
        + "&endblock=99999999"
        + "&page=1"
        + "&offset=10"
        + "&sort=asc"
        + "&apikey=" + API_KEY
    );

    // the API returns transaction both `from` and `to` the address
    // this filter is unnecessary for contract addresses (as there are no transactions `from` a contract)
    return response.data.result.filter((item) => {
        // mind that the API might return the params in lowercase, while your input address might be checksum
        return item.to.toLowerCase() === address.toLowerCase();
    });
}

const _filterTransactionsBySelector = (allTransactions, selector) => {
    return allTransactions.filter((item) => {
        return item?.input.startsWith(selector);
    });
}

const _getTransactionHashes = (transactions) => {
    return transactions.map((item) => {
        return item.hash;
    });
}

run();
```

Which prints hashes of transaction invoking the specified `mint()` function (just this one specified by the selector - not the other one).

```
[
  '0xd6a141780585e0833382cfa5940db4bd1b2acde8108c949421242077d6a5d16d',
  '0x63bfaae7afbd50f1ee052182aeee7147ba256c6285bc2783f8607a881dbf135f',
  '0x57cd8c74c13aded28841f14a79b1901a5e12a87aae38ea4f8af19a7ef976e281',
  '0x8dbbb9f7fa11ec0c025d1cec2ac75862a89dc10fe69d4599f2401db2a089c0c9',
  '0x34fa6285fbf63313127422be8b84214906642a2399b971e863b0b7950bd57ca4',
  '0x4fcab773f03ed5f12b85c2329e14226b5afb4120e9227e8da423bd7d88fb06ed',
  '0x67d540059dcf9d6c6a63e03f8882fe1522897d09c03f9185c540c807cf1972b8'
]
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the total count directly ? Because this API has limit of 10000 total transactions.

Comment: @Kundan As described in the answer, there's no way to get this transaction count directly - that's why we're doing this calculation in the script. If you need a larger scope, you can find another third-party data provider allowing to request larger scope, or you can run your own Polygon node publishing an RPC-API to your application without any limit.